# QtCreator's designer doesn't use size bindings

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qt-quick

I am trying to make a UI using QuickQT and QML and the designer in QtCreator does not render the shapes properly if they are bound to a variable.

```
ApplicationWindow {

    height : maximumHeight
    width : maximumWidth

 Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
```

If I do that, I can't see the elements in Design Tab, what should I do to make them visible ?

[image: kanban]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Qt wiki http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/quick-screens.html#setting-bindings

> Qt Quick Designer cannot show bindings and using them might have a
>   negative impact on performance, so consider setting anchors and
>   margins for items, instead.